# list of JSON object in a data frame was converted into string

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame. The last column, "entities," is a list of dictionaries.

```
dict0 = [{'name': 'require-once', 'type': 'OTHER', 'mid': None, 'wikipediaUrl': None, 'numMentions': 4, 'avgSalience': 0.014624}, {'name': 'require_once', 'type': 'OTHER', 'mid': None, 'wikipediaUrl': None, 'numMentions': 4, 'avgSalience': 0.008366},{'name': 'funkytaurusmedia.com/includes/header.php', 'type': 'UNKNOWN', 'mid': '/m/02dnj_', 'wikipediaUrl': 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Header_(computing)', 'numMentions': 2, 'avgSalience': 0.007887},{'name': 'public_html', 'type': 'UNKNOWN', 'mid': '/m/03g20', 'wikipediaUrl': 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML', 'numMentions': 28, 'avgSalience': 0.007139}, {'name': 'public_html', 'type': 'PERSON', 'mid': None, 'wikipediaUrl': None, 'numMentions': 1, 'avgSalience': 0.007139}]
dict1 = [{'name': 'require-once1', 'type': 'OTHER', 'mid': None, 'wikipediaUrl': None, 'numMentions': 4, 'avgSalience': 0.014624}, {'name': 'require_once', 'type': 'OTHER', 'mid': None, 'wikipediaUrl': None, 'numMentions': 4, 'avgSalience': 0.008366},{'name': 'funkytaurusmedia.com/includes/header.php', 'type': 'UNKNOWN', 'mid': '/m/02dnj_', 'wikipediaUrl': 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Header_(computing)', 'numMentions': 2, 'avgSalience': 0.007887},{'name': 'public_html', 'type': 'UNKNOWN', 'mid': '/m/03g20', 'wikipediaUrl': 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML', 'numMentions': 28, 'avgSalience': 0.007139}]
df = pd.DataFrame({"date":{0:1522254600000, 1:1132254600000 },"url":{0:"http", 1:"http1"},"lang":{0:"de", 1:"de"},"polarity":{0:-0.8, 1:0.8},"magnitude":{0:10.3, 1:11},"score":{0:-0.5, 1:0.5},"entities": {0:dict0, 1:dict1}})
df
```

I saved this data to a csv file using the following line.

```
df.to_csv('GEG.csv', index = False, header=True)
```

then, I uploaded it to the drive and read it from a colab notebook using the following code.

```
dataFrame = pd.read_csv("drive/MyDrive/GEG.csv")
```

After reading it, I was trying to make some processes on the column "entities," but I found out that somewhere along the process of saving and reading the data, the last column was converted to a string.
Is there a way to save this data frame and read it again without changing the format of the last column(list of dictionaries)?

Comment: you can try to cast the column in number (or int) with df['col'].astype('int32') ?

Comment: @Tomo ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[{\'name\': \'Sign\', \'type\': \'CONSUMER_GOOD\', \'mid\': None,

Answer (score 0):

You basically have two options here.

You could pickle the dataframe, then when you reload it it will be like it was.

I prefer to use [json.loads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) to handle these kinds of tasks.

After you read from csv, apply json.loads to the column that has valid json inside it.

```py
import json
df['col_with_json_str'] = df['col_with_json_str'].apply(lambda x: json.loads(x))
```

If your dictionaries aren't valid json, you need to use `ast.literal_eval`. This is still better than eval, which you shouldn't use.

```py
import ast
dataFrame = pd.read_csv("GEG.csv")
dataFrame['entities'] = dataFrame['entities'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

Don't use eval, unless you really don't care about security. See:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!

Comment: this error happened when I tried your code "JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3 (char 2)"

Comment: d'oh, the 'None' values make this difficult to read as json.

Comment: You need to use ast.literal eval, I'll update my answer

Comment: @Shaheen did ast.literal_eval work? It worked when I ran your code sample?